# can we stop vibrate and play sound when push notification comes (ios)?

Tags: ios, push-notification

I know the ways for,
 1.how to stop playing sound and stop vibrating(simultaneously) while push notification comes from server to iPhone device 
 2.Only playing vibrate with no sound.

but I did not find any way to **"play only sound and stop vibrating when new push notification comes"** on device.

Comment: u get any solution .. so plz help me....

Comment: No you can not stop vibrating when user explicitly put phone on vibrate mode.

Comment: so we can not set only sound ? in general mode also?

Comment: in general mode if user does not set vibrate on then it will only play sound

Comment: yes than how yo play only sound in general mode ?

Comment: adding "sound" property in Payload plays a sound.

Comment: yes but in sound property set any sound name ?Please share proper Dictionary format?

Comment: {
"aps" : {

        "alert" : "You got your emails.",

        "badge" : 9,

        "sound" : "bingbong.aiff"

    },

    "acme1" : "bar",

    "acme2" : 42

}

Comment: "sound" : "bingbong.aiff" we set default sound file name for play sound ?

Comment: yes you can set any sound over there, in case of default sound just put value "default" over there.

Comment: but in default value get sound and vibrate both bro... that's problem in set default value key

Comment: I think you did not read the question and answer properly then either you can stop both, or only stop sound. but you can not play sound only if user set vibration mode.

Comment: no user set only general mode and not set vibrate than we can get only sound without vibrate ?

Comment: yes, please try with that first

Comment: like this { "aps" : { "alert" : "You got your emails.", "badge" : 9, "sound" : "bingbong.aiff" }, "acme1" : "bar", "acme2" : 42 }   ???

Comment: { "aps" : { "alert" : "You got your emails.", "badge" : 9, "sound" : "default" } }

Comment: this way {"aps":{"alert":"Hello from APNs Tester.","badge":"1","sound":"default"}} get both sound and vibrate..

Comment: test via APN Tester..

Comment: ParthPandya.... u there ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long answer: when the phone is set on vibrate, it is not possible to set it so that it will play a sound. The other way around is possible - vibrating without sound, when a push notification is received.

Comment: Also this my same question. i want only get sound not vibrate.. so plz say other way...